# content of the page is not displaying getting empty page

Tags: wp-load.php

```
<body>

    <div id="wrapper">
<h2>1stWebDesigner PHP Template</h2>
<ul>

<?php wp_list_pages('title_li=');?>
</ul>

</div> <!-- end #nav -->

<div id="content">

     <?php if(have_posts()) :while (have_posts()) : the_posts();?>
<h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
<?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; endif;?>

</div> <!-- end #content -->

<div id="sidebar">
Navigation

Home
About Us
Links
Portfolio
Contact
Box Two

Link Here
Link Here
Link Here
Link Here
Link Here
Box Three

Link Here
Link Here
Link Here
Link Here
Link Here
</div> <!-- end #sidebar -->
Copyright &copy 2010 1stWebDesigner.com PHP Template

    </div> <!-- End #wrapper -->

</body>
```

i used this code to display the content but am getting blank page

Comment: Based on your question, there is no way to know what you are trying to do. Please improve your question, for example - is this a templatefile? Where do you call it? What did you try so far?

Comment: if you are getting empty page then you have probably a php syntax error

Comment: I suggest you enable WP_DEBUG, and read up on how to activate xdebug, and where to find/activate PHP error logs. You may be getting blank white screens on errors now, but there is better error handling out there

Answer (score 2):

The function is called `the_post()` (no plural *s*).